# Filtering a range by multiple operations

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have some price list data (of different supplier price lists) of the columnar format below:

WEEK,SUPPLIER,BRAND,PRODUCT_CODE,TITLE,COST,STOCK

WEEK is of the format WKXX (where XX=01 to 52) e.g. WK12

I would like to filter the range (and get the same columns back) to get a result where we have the the minimum cost for every PRODUCT_CODE. However, the issue is that often multiple suppliers have the same minimum cost for a given product so this would result in multiple rows per product. If this is the case, I would like this filtered further by the MAX week so only rows with the max week appear. Even then, sometimes some suppliers have the same cost for a given product in any given week, in this case, I would like the results filtered further by MAX stock.

So overall the logic is (in order): minimum cost --> max week --> max stock. Overall, each product code should only appear once in the results.

I have tried using FILTER, QUERY, and other methods but this is racking my brains.

Can the above logic be accomplished with a single formula?

Comment: I recommend trying the code yourself and then ask specific question when you have problems.  As it stand now your question is too broad.

Comment: I think this is more of a spreadsheet question than a scripting question, if you're able to share a sample spreadsheet, we may be able to help. It's possible that you'd need some intermediary tables before getting the final result you want.